# "No such accessible method: setFields() on object: java.util.ArrayList" when using Apache Digester

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I'm currently trying to consume a list of strings from some XML using Apache Digester, as described in the [How do I add literal elements to a List object?](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Digester/FAQ) section of the FAQ.

I'm hitting the following error:

```
[DEBUG] Digester - [SetNextRule]{job/editorial/articlegroup/article} Call java.util.ArrayList.setFields([This, This, is, is, a, a, test, test, , , , ])
[ERROR] Digester - End event threw exception <java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: setFields() on object: java.util.ArrayList>java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: setFields() on object: java.util.ArrayList
```

A simplified version of the XML I am using is as follows:

```
<job>
    <editorial>
        <articlegroup>
            <article>
                <text>
                    <content><![CDATA[This]]></content>
                </text>
                <text>
                    <content><![CDATA[is]]></content>
                </text>
                <text>
                    <content><![CDATA[a]]></content>
                </text>
                <text>
                    <content><![CDATA[test]]></content>
                </text>
            </article>
        </articlegroup>
    </editorial>
</job>
```

And the source code:

```
public class PPJob {

    List<String> fields;

    public List<String> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    public void setFields(List<String> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}


addObjectCreate("job", PPJob.class);
addSetProperties("job");

addObjectCreate("job/editorial/articlegroup/article", ArrayList.class);
addCallMethod("job/editorial/articlegroup/article/text/content", "add", 1);
addCallParam("job/editorial/articlegroup/article/text/content", 0);
addSetNext("job/editorial/articlegroup/article", "setFields");

PPJob result = (PPJob)super.parse([THE XML]);
```

I'm pretty much a novice at using the Digester, and I'm having a hard time tracking down examples for what I need.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this question earned me the "Tumbleweed" badge, and I'm struggling to find some way to re-word the problem so it is easier to comprehend. So here's an update on my progress:

I decided to abandon the Commons Digester in the end, time constraints made it difficult to chase up the issue up further and as a result I haven't logged a bug to the Digester project (if someone else does let me know and I'll share my experience).

The javax XPath functions proved more straightforward for achieving my requirement, I resolved to this solution:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
rootQuery = xPath.compile("/job");
textFieldsQuery = xPath.compile("/job/editorial/articlegroup/article/text|/job/editorial/articlegroup/article/flashtext");

Node rootNode = (Node)rootQuery.evaluate(new InputSource(is), XPathConstants.NODE);

PPJob job = new PPJob();
Map<String, String> jobTextFields = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
NodeList fields = (NodeList)query.evaluate(rootNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < fields.getLength(); i++) {
    Node field = fields.item(i);
    String fieldName = field.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
    String fieldContent = field.getNextSibling().getNodeValue();
    jobTextFields.put(fieldName, fieldContent);
}       
job.setTextFields(jobTextFields);
```

If anyone has a suggestion for this problem I'm still interested to hear why I had so much trouble with the Digester.

Comment: this is not an answer for your question, don't write it as is, and don't mark as the correct one, please.

Comment: @logoff - untrue.  If the poster says it solved their problem (as they do here), then it is a **resolution** to the question.  Sometimes the solution is a change of requirements.

Comment: @logoff I would be more than happy to mark your answer as the correct one if it resolves the problem more concisely. However Chris is right, the answer to my question was to rethink my approach, which is also what I currently recommend to others.

Comment: Why is it not an answer?

Comment: Answers presenting alternative approaches to the problem are certainly acceptable.  From the help center:  "*The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful...*"  You might find it to be a bit too much of a departure for comfort, but sounds like it got the asker going in the right direction to me, and seems to be a pretty solid "try this instead" style answer.

Comment: I like you found an alternative technology to solve your problem, but as yshavit said, this is not an answer for your question. your question is about Apache Digester, not about a general problem parsing XML documents. I'm aware of femtoRgon comment, but I agree more with yshavit one.

Comment: Alternative approaches are certainly an acceptable answer. If you disagree then you should start a discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead of cluttering the comment section of this answer.